# Is it possible to extract the method name from the response object?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I'm using REST-Assured in Java and here's how I'm getting my `response` object:

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).header(header_name).get();
```

I want to know if there's any way to extract the method name used (`GET` in this case) from the `response` object.

Comment: Why would you try to get the _request_ method from the _response_?

Comment: About the only way you can possibly do that is by accessing response metadata. And even then, I doubt that it is guaranteed to contain anything of that sort.

Comment: @Thomas I need it for logging purposes.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I checked nearly all the methods available for the `response` object, but none of them help. How do you suggest to access the response metadata?

Comment: I'm not sure you correctly understood my intent: since you're after the request method you should look into the `Request` object and not the response.

Comment: @Thomas I got that, but I do not really have anything like a `Request` object in my code, I'm storing my response in a `Response` object. Hence the question.

Comment: I don't know REST-Assured but from the documentation it seems that since you call `.get()` in the end this will result in a GET request. SInce this seems to be client code and since the client needs to know whether it was a GET request or anything else I doubt you can extract that information from the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase if you're interested in knowing the requested method say GET or POST, below code will print the method on the console

```
given().log().method()
        .when()
        .get("https://www.google.co.in/").then().statusCode(200);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome! That works for me, thanks a lot! Just wondering if it's possible to route the log to log4j logger object.

Comment: Answering my question above, I wrote a wrapper class which takes a log4j logger as constructor argument and offers a PrintStream whose flush() method writes the written content to the supplied log4j logger. More details at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33388510/6676240. I modified the `myStringBuilder` to a `String` object and added a check inside `flush()` method as below:
             `if(!myStringBuilder.equals(""))
              logger.info(this.myStringBuilder.toString());`