# Intercepting an assignment in Java

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm using REST-Assured library with TestNG for receiving the response in a `Response` object as below.

```
Response response;

@Test
public void someTest() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "some_valid_baseURI";
    RestAssured.basePath = "some_valid_endpoint";
    response =    RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).when().get();
}
```

I have several test methods like the above-mentioned method in a test class. Is there any way to intercept the response assignment so that I can, somewhere else (e.g. in a method annotated by an `@AfterMethod`), know that the method being used to get the response is the `GET` method?

PS: I did not find any in-built way in the REST-Assured library to do this.

Comment: I do not think you can use rest assured for this but you can store the information you need in variable and later can use that.

Comment: That would need me to do that for every test out there. Not a very good idea. Instead, I was thinking of some generic interceptor-like method which would work for all the test methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in [Is it possible to extract the method name from the response object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203377/is-it-possible-to-extract-the-method-name-from-the-response-object) serves my purpose for this question. Sorry about the generic question line here though!